# How do you split HTML code between two lines?

Tags: html

I have a very long line of HTML. I tried turning:

```
<code><othercode>
```

into

```
<code><
othercode>
```

But it breaks the HTML, and I tried:

```
<code>
<othercode>
```

But it puts a space between the images. In python you can just put a '\' at the end of the line. Is there something similar in HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't separate the opening of the tag (<) from the tag identifier (in this case, "othercode"). So this won't work:

```
<code><
othercode params=...>
```

but this will:

```
<code><othercode
params=...>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
<code><othercode
id="something">
```

Even this might be ok:

```
<code><othercode
><morecode>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<code
><othercode>
```

or

```
<code><othercode
>
```